# Angular 12: Schema validation failed with the following errors: Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(inlineStyleLanguage)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular12

After updating my angular project from 11 to 12 I'm getting the following error when I try to run

```
ng build --prod
```

> Schema validation failed with the following errors:
> Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(inlineStyleLanguage).

I tried deleting `node_modules` folder and running `npm install` still it gives same error.

Can someone please help me with this.
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

you can run `ng v` to look at all the versions, and make sure they are all up to date by  running `ng update @angular/cli` and so on.

if You want to solve exactly that issue and nothing else, go to angular.json and search for the property `inlineStyleLanguage` and remove it. that property may have been added while using a cli that you have changed later.